# JavaScript Name Space

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I wanna implement the Name Space concept in my JavaScript code, I am using ExtJS, but I don't know where to start, anyone could help me? The site example is very short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good sample [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)

and here is too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/JavaScript_Object_Management

Comment: Broken second link :(

Comment: Just find in google 'Javascript Namespace'. 1 result for example: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/

Comment: You should still update your answer if somebody tells you that your answer is no longer *competent*.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in ExtJS4 the App name is your name space. So for example if you define your app this way:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    appFolder: 'app', 
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    controllers: [
        'MyController'
        ],
    launch: function() {
        console.log('hello');

        // This is fired as soon as the page is ready
    }
});​
```

then all of your components you define need to be namespaced with `MyApp`. So a controller becomes `MyApp.controller.MyController` and a view becomes `MyApp.view.InboxGrid`

Comment: So Namespace was not what I expected, I have a controller with many lines of code, I just wanted to better organize this functionality by separating code, I thought that this was possible using namespace. For example, I have code that saves a student and a code that saves a teacher within the same controller, I wanted to better organize in different files.

Comment: You can have more than one controller if thats what you are after.

Comment: I want to have 2 controllers, but I would to call the functions in just one controller, do you understand what I want to do ?

- 1 Controller to student functions
- 1 controller to teacher functions

and 1 controller to manage this functions.

Comment: I am afraid I am not following your line of thinking. There are Architecture guides to MVC on the Sencha site - perhaps it would help following their suggested way of structuring your app.